# Plot rolling/moving average in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Looking for a way to plot rolling/moving average in d3 without having to manipulate the data in advance. So I want to smooth out the line by averaging each data point with the two after it. My code is like this

```
var data = [3, 66, 2, 76, 5, 20, 1, 3, 8, 90, 2, 5, 70];

var w = 20,
    h = 80;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, w]);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .rangeRound([h, 0]);

var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", w * data.length -1)
    .attr("height", h);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d); })


var movingAverageLine = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d); })

chart.append("svg:path").attr("d", line(data));
chart.append("svg:path").attr("d", movingAverageLine(data));
```

Can I specify movingAverageLine to calculate the average of the following data points? I can't think of a way to access them in that function.

I have set up an example on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tjjjohnson/XXFrg/2/#run

Answer (score 12):

A previous solution results in a *cumulative* moving average.

[I modified the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plmrry/ktLtN/) made by [John O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255689/john-oconnor) to provide an [*n*-moving average](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MovingAverage.html) by passing a custom interpolation function to `d3.svg.line()`:

```
movingAvg = function(n) {
    return function (points) {
        points = points.map(function(each, index, array) {
            var to = index + n - 1;
            var subSeq, sum;
            if (to < points.length) {
                subSeq = array.slice(index, to + 1);
                sum = subSeq.reduce(function(a,b) { 
                    return [a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1]]; 
                });
                return sum.map(function(each) { return each / n; });
            }
            return undefined;
        });
        points = points.filter(function(each) { return typeof each !== 'undefined' })
        // Note that one could re-interpolate the points 
        // to form a basis curve (I think...)
        return points.join("L");
    }
}
var movingAverageLine = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .y(function(d,i) { return y(d); })
    .interpolate(movingAvg(6));
```

Comment: Great work there. However, I cannot make it work with another interpolation (like "monotone"). Any idea on how to go with that?

Comment: hi people from the future. here is an update for d3 v4. please thank the answerers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386083/plot-rolling-moving-average-in-d3-js-v4/41388581#41388581

Answer (score 2):

The following line function should do what you want. Formula based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average.

```
var _movingSum;
var movingAverageLine = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d,i) { return x(i); })
.y(function(d,i) {
    if (i == 0) {
        return _movingSum = 0;
    } else {
        _movingSum += d;
    }
    return y(_movingSum / i);
})
.interpolate("basis");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XXFrg/12/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "rolling mean", but if you want to just have a line that shows the mean of your data, here is an approach:

```
chart.append("svg:line")
     .attr("x1", x(0))
     .attr("x2", x(1))
     .attr("y1", d3.mean(data))
     .attr("y2", d3.mean(data))
    .style('stroke', 'blue')
     .style('stroke-width', 1)
```

You can see the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/XXFrg/3/.  Hope that helps,

Comment: Edited question to clarify a little. By "rolling" I mean using the average of several points on each day e.g. three day average. This is to smooth out the line.

Comment: I think you would have to change the data -- when you pass the array to a d3 function, it will iterate through 1 item at a time.  Any reason you can't just create another array to pass?

Comment: no reason I can't modify the data, I was just wondering if there was some crafty d3 awesomeness that might do it well