# Plot rolling/moving average in d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

this is a necessary update to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963352/plot-rolling-moving-average-in-d3-js) asked for d3 v3.

as mentioned here https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#shapes-d3-shape

> 4.0 introduces a new curve API for specifying how line and area shapes interpolate between data points. The line.interpolate and area.interpolate methods have been replaced with line.curve and area.curve. Curves are implemented using the curve interface rather than as a function that returns an SVG path data string; this allows curves to render to either SVG or Canvas. In addition, line.curve and area.curve now take a function which instantiates a curve for a given context, rather than a string.

this is a shocking amount of change and breaks all prior examples unless I'm missing something extremely obvious. of course, the new line.curve documentation https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line_curve is less than helpful:

> ## line.curve([curve]) <>
>
> If curve is specified, sets the curve factory and returns this line
>   generator. If curve is not specified, returns the current curve
>   factory, which defaults to curveLinear.

I am extremely lost and there are no good examples out there. Can anyone please update the above question ([Plot rolling/moving average in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963352/plot-rolling-moving-average-in-d3-js)) for d3 v4?

thanks very much. I've wasted too many hours on this already :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answer is really good and is probably **the best way** to achieve your aims.  But for posterity's sake, here's a n-moving-average in the new d3-shape *[curve factory](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#custom-curves)* methodology:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    function NMoveAvg(context, N) {
      this._context = context;
      this._points = {
        x: [],
        y: []
      };
      this._N = N;
    }

    NMoveAvg.prototype = {
      areaStart: function() {
        this._line = 0;
      },
      areaEnd: function() {
        this._line = NaN;
      },
      lineStart: function() {
        this._point = 0;
      },
      lineEnd: function() {
        if (this._line || (this._line !== 0 && this._point === 1)) this._context.closePath();
        this._line = 1 - this._line;
      },
      point: function(x, y) {
        x = +x, y = +y;

        this._points.x.push(x);
        this._points.y.push(y);

        if (this._points.x.length < this._N) return;

        var aX = this._points.x.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
          }, 0) / this._N,
          aY = this._points.y.reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b;
          }, 0) / this._N;

        this._points.x.shift();
        this._points.y.shift();

        switch (this._point) {
          case 0:
            this._point = 1;
            this._line ? this._context.lineTo(aX, aY) : this._context.moveTo(aX, aY);
            break;
          case 1:
            this._point = 2; // proceed
          default:
            this._context.lineTo(aX, aY);
            break;
        }
      }
    };

    var curveNMoveAge = (function custom(N) {

      function nMoveAge(context) {
        return new NMoveAvg(context, N);
      }

      nMoveAge.N = function(N) {
        return custom(+N);
      };

      return nMoveAge;
    })(0);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [3, 66, 2, 76, 5, 20, 1, 30, 50, 9, 80, 5, 7];

    var w = 500,
      h = 500;

    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 12])
      .range([0, w]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([0, h]);

    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);


    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d, i) {
        return x(i);
      })
      .y(function(d, i) {
        return y(d);
      });

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("d", line.curve(curveNMoveAge.N(3)))
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "steelblue");

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("d", line.curve(d3.curveLinear))
      .style("fill", "none")
      .style("stroke", "black");
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for doing this, it is important to help me and other newbies learn the curve factory methodology (which is the implied question here i guess.)

Comment: i am actually going to adopt your answer because it forces me to learn curve factory. thank you once again.

Comment: How can the line for the average be smoothed out? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/plmrry/ktLtN/

Comment: @Babak, This is one of the reasons I recommended that the OP to this question adopt snolflake's answer.  The d3's new curvefactory methodology does not make it easy to mix interpolater factories.  If you want to do that you'd have to create one that combines the two point by point.

Answer (score 8):

They're actually using d3.v2 so maybe their options were limited back then. But on d3.v4 I don't see the need of a custom curve factory when simply calculating the moving average and plotting it with a `curveBasis` gives you the exact same result.

Below you can find a simplified and updated fiddle for the question you mentioned.

```js
movingAvg = function (data, neighbors) {
  return data.map((val, idx, arr) => {
    let start = Math.max(0, idx - neighbors), end = idx + neighbors
    let subset = arr.slice(start, end + 1)
    let sum = subset.reduce((a,b) => a + b)
    return sum / subset.length
  })
}

var data = [3, 66, 2, 76, 5, 20, 1, 30, 50, 9, 80, 5, 7]
var dataAvg = movingAvg(data, 1)

console.log(data.length, data)
console.log(dataAvg.length, dataAvg)

var w = 20,
    h = 80

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, w])
    
var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .rangeRound([h, 0])


var straightLine = d3.line()
    .x((d,i) => x(i))
    .y(d => y(d))
    
var curvedLine = d3.line()
    .x((d,i) => x(i))
    .y(d => y(d))
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)

window.onload = function() {
 var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", w * data.length -1)
  .attr("height", h + 200)

 chart
  .append('path')
  .attr('class', 'avg')
  .datum(dataAvg)
  .attr('d', curvedLine)

 chart
  .append('path')
  .datum(data)
  .attr('d', straightLine)
}
```

```css
path {
    stroke: black;
    fill: none;
}
.avg {
    stroke: #ff0000;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```